# Invoke-command unable to copy a shared network folder?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have been working on a script that can remove an old version of zabbix from our servers, and install the latest version.

I am having a problem copying a file from a shared folder when I am using invoke-command.

I can run this script directly from the target machine and I can copy the folder perfectly:

```
$Installer = '\\Server01\Zabbix'
Write-Host -f green "[INFO]: Attempting to copy the folder located on $installer." 
 
 
 try{
 Copy-Item -Path  $installer -Destination c:\ -recurse -force
 Write-Host -f green "[INFO]: $installer is succesfully copied on C:\Zabbix on $env:computername." }
 catch
 {write-host -f red "[ERROR]: Copying $installer encountered an error on $env:computername : $error"
 $error.clear()}
```

Since I will be running this on multiple servers, I chose the method:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{}
```

here is a sample code:

```
$servers = @( 'Server02')

foreach ($server in $servers) {
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {

 $Installer = '\\Server01\Zabbix'
Write-Host -f green "[INFO]: Attempting to copy the folder located on $installer." 
 
 try{
 Copy-Item -Path  $installer -Destination c:\ -recurse -force
 Write-Host -f green "[INFO]: $installer is succesfully copied on C:\Zabbix on $env:computername." }
 catch
 {write-host -f red "[ERROR]: Copying $installer encountered an error on $env:computername : $error"
 $error.clear()}

}}
```

and below is the error message:

```
[INFO]: Attempting to copy the folder located on \\Server01\Zabbix.
Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\Server01\Zabbix:String) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : Server02
Cannot find path '\\Server01\Zabbix' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\Server01\Zabbix:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : Server02
```

I am using the same accounts, when accessing server 02 directly and running the commands without invoke-command. Access should be fine.

can anyone help?

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a [double hop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.4) problem.

Comment: The user account which is used here has  permission to shared folder? As the error says permission denied / Path not found. Try login with the user account in the destination machine and see if you can see the file or folder specified.

Comment: Use a File Explorer from same machine you are running the failed PS script and see if you have access by using \\Server01\Zabbix.  The issue is probably a permissions.  It may be a domain issue.  All machines have to be in the same domain.  Adding the domain in front of the server name may solve issue.

Comment: It was a double hop problem as advised by boxdog.
access was working fine, but my script is as advised, was doing a doublehop. 

I change a few lines in the code, and used new-pssession method for file copy. For the rest of the lines, I used Invoke-command method.

works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell doesn't support `second-hop` out of the box.

I.e You invoke the command remotely with you credentials on `Server1`.
When `Server1` in turn tries to access resources on `Server2`, it hasn't access to your credentials as you normally don't pass them forward for further use.

In that case you either need to allow the credentials of the computer account of `Server1` to access `Server2` or use a method that will either allow passing along your credentials or allow account delegation.

See [MS Learn - Making the second hop in PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.4)

`CredSSP` used to be the prefered option, but MS has put some further restrictions on using CredSSP which might make it fail.

So I would opt for using `JEA` (Just Enough Administration) instead if you don't have access to `Kerberos delegation` in the AD.

A third option is to use `SSH` for `PowerShell` remoting instead, as SSH actually do store your credentials on each hop. But that doesn't work with `Windows PowerShell 5.1` or earlier.